# how do I make sure a particular user is the one logged in?

Tags: django, django-views

so I have some code which creates a user but how do I make sure every url that the user goes to will be in his/her own `user session` such that `request.user` will be the user I created?

```
def liked(request):

try:
    sp = Spotify(auth_manager=oauth)
    liked = sp.current_user_saved_tracks(limit=30)['items']
    spotify_user = sp.current_user()
    user__ , created = 
    User.objects.get_or_create(username=spotify_user['uri'], 
    first_name=spotify_user["display_name"])
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user__)[0]
```

i have other views i want only accessible to the `user` created or gotten from the `get_or_create`, i reckon I'd have to use the `@login_required` decorator but then again I do not know what constitutes this "login" with respect to the user I created. How do I do ensure that `user` is the logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

Django's default `MIDDLEWARE` takes care of this for you.
In every `request` object or `self.request` there is a `user` object.
Django checks the session via the cookie that the browser sends with every request, and puts the user object in the current request.

An example in a Class based view:

```
class ExampleView(TemplateView):
    template = 'example.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExampleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        users_data = ExampleData.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So once I create the user with `get_or_create`, it automatically associates that user with the current session?

Comment: No, the user's browser must use an authentication process, and will then relate the browser's session cookie to a User.

Comment: The python-social-auth framework has a spotify backend  https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/spotify.html#oauth2. It's fairly easy to integrate into django.

Answer (score 0):

Once a user is logged in, every other page is put into the session. Just log that user in first.

Comment: My question is, how do I log that user in?

Comment: You can log a user simply by using the [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) as  per the documentation. Check out [User Authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/) to guide you

Comment: You can try what @Mugoma suggested up there or try the login function. All documentation about these are in Django official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the user is logged in

In class based views;
if self.request.user.is_authenticated

In function based view

if request.user.is_authenticated

Answer (score 0):

Ok as i understand you need to limit some users to access some pages and not for others .. i suggest to use permissions way

- add permission to any Model you Have Like this [image]
- then when you create your special user do this to assign this permission to him like that : `myuser.user_permissions.add('can_view_all_clients', 'another_perm', ...)`

**For Function Based Views :**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required("YourModel.can_view_all_clients")
def your_special_view(request):
    return 'your view'
```

**For Class Based View :**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import DetailView


class ModelDetailView(PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = "model_detail.html"
    model = Model
    permission_required = "can_view_all_clients"
```